ran the npm run dev first time on course careers using vs code and i get this error message but the favicon.ico is only 26kb
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-metadata-route-loader.js?filePath=C%3A%5CUsers%5Ctoobl%5CDesktop%5COT's%20Business%5CCourse%20Careers%5Capp%5Csrc%5Capp%5Cfavicon.ico&isDynamicRouteExtension=0!?next_metadata_route
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (11:83)
|   const fileSizeInMB = buffer.byteLength / 1024 / 1024
|   if (fileSizeInMB > 8) {

throw new Error('File size for Open Graph image "C:\\Users\\toobl\\Desktop\\OT's Business\\Course Careers\\app\\src\\app\\favicon.ico" exceeds 8MB. ' +


|     (Current: ${fileSizeInMB.toFixed(2)}MB) |  +
Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/next/dist/build/webpack/loaders/next-metadata-route-loader.js?filePath=C%3A%5CUsers%5Ctoobl%5CDesktop%5COT's%20Business%5CCourse%20Careers%5Capp%5Csrc%5Capp%5Cfavicon.ico&isDynamicRouteExtension=0!?next_metadata_route

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
